# Insert boolean true / false to Postgres and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, pdo

i fight with DB, trying to insert true and false values to my table with column boolean, but always getting just error:

> Invalid parameter number

tested with:

```
$value = true
$value = "true"
$value = 1
```

Can somebody please advise me?
Thanks

EDIT:
full code would looks like:

```
// adding value to variabile
                    if (empty($row['vin']))
                        $vin = 0;                   
                    else
                        $vin = 1;
//calling insert method
$this->insertToTable($model_code, $typ, $kind, $ts, $vin,  $smr, $ire, $manufacturer_code);

//full insert method:
    public function insertToTable($code, $name, $kind, $ts, $vin, $smr, $ire, $manufacturer_code)
    {                   
        try {                                       
            $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS );            
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );            
            $sql = "INSERT INTO r_vehicle_model(code, name, kind, ts, vin, smr, ire, manufacturer_code) VALUES(:code, :name, :kind, :ts, :smr, :ire, :manufacturer_code)";
            $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( 'code', $code, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'kind', $kind, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'ts', $ts, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'vin', $vin, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'smr', $smr, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'ire', $ire, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->bindValue( 'manufacturer_code', $manufacturer_code, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
            $stmt->execute();                
            }
        catch( PDOException $e ) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }           
    }
```

full error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :vin

Comment: What is your column type ?

Comment: my column type is : boolean

Comment: Then `$value = 1` should work. Can you post your query ?

Comment: I'm using `'true'/'false'` on Laravel

Comment: can you post your query

Comment: And post the **exact error message** because that could be simply that you have a different number of column names to the number of data parameters

Comment: added query + adding value to variabile

Comment: 7 placeholders and 8 parameters, that doesn't match.... "Invalid parameter number"

Comment: DAMM IT! I see it now, sorry I should see it earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget `:vin` in insert query. Number of parameter in values is not equal to `bindValue`

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO r_vehicle_model(code, name, kind, ts, vin, smr, ire, manufacturer_code) VALUES(:code, :name, :kind, :ts, ,:vin ,:smr, :ire, :manufacturer_code)";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using `PDO::PARAM_STR` to specify that all the parameters you're passing are strings.

You should make choose the appropriate type for the field, so for a boolean consider using `PDO::PARAM_BOOL`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php